# Unable to create MD5 Hash file?

Tags: java, android, hash, md5

My error is :
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'D:\Android\AsianNEws\PNRstatus\app\libs\httpclient-4.3.6.jar'.

My Gradle file is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp_pc.pnrstatus"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
   // compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
   // compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I got the same Error Because of Spell Mistake in

```
compile files('lib/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')  and solved by correcting the spelling to libs
```

Please Check the Spellings Correctly Or You may try this

```
  compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar','libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar','libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
```

PS: **HttpClient** was Deprecated One and Not Recommended. Please Consider **[OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)** for future Projects

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem.just changed **libs** to **lib** and it worked.
Check the spells correctly.